# Google Changed Keyword Tool URL?

Tags: php, web-scraping

I've been using the following code to scrape keywords from Google:

```
  $data=file_get_contents('http://clients1.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&gl=us&q='.$keyword);
```

However, my script has suggest started showing these errors:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://clients1.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&gl=us&q=money) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in /home/username/public_html/keywords.php on line 10
```

I'm guessing this is being caused by Google changing the link?  Does anyone know what the new link would be or what I need to change in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$url = 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&client=firefox&hl=en-US&q=';

$data=file_get_contents($url . urlencode( $keyword ) );
```

Hope it helps.